# How do I supress the "2 files to edit" message in vimdiff?

Tags: vim

'vimdiff a b' always prints "2 files to edit".  I don't want to see that.  How can I avoid it?

Here is an example:

```
⚡ vimdiff  a b                                                                                                                               
2 files to edit
```

I want to use vimdiff from a bash script and don't want to see this output

Comment: You could of course just launch it with `2>/dev/null`. Why do you need this?It seems like such a minor annoyance. Oh, on a completely irrelevant note, could you share your $PS1? What is the character you are using as a prompt?

Comment: vimdiff a b 2>/dev/null does not work for me.

Comment: I'm just sticking the unicode character in there.  My $PS1 is defined here: https://github.com/kablamo/dotfiles/blob/master/links/.bash/prompt.sh

Comment: Nice, thanks :). And you're right, redirecting STDERR does not seem to work. I thought it did, but I just didn't see the line.

Comment: The answer seems to be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/645736/1081936). Make sure to read the comments.

Comment: Hey @terdon, if you like that, you should check out vim's "digraph" page (`:help digraph`). It has all the symbols it supports with hex, decimal, descriptions, and digraphs themselves (key sequences, usually decent mnemonics.) Of course you can go the other way and pipe symbols to `hd`, so you can print by numeric value from your config files (generally a better idea than pasting them directly.)

Comment: @JohnP I have no idea what you're talking about. Did you mean to address the comment to the OP? I don't even use vim, I'm an emacs user. I just left a link to a page that might help the OP.

Comment: "Oh, on a completely irrelevant note, could you share your $PS1? What is the character you are using as a prompt? – terdon" Although yes, it won't help you without Vim.

Comment: @JohnP oh, wow, that was 4 years ago when I had barely heard of unicode :) The character is `U+26A1 ‹⚡› \N{HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN}` and has nothing to do with vim at all. That's the value given to `PS1` and is not related to editors. It is a shell issue, not a vim one.

Comment: Haha, okay, I didn't see the age. My comment was all about special characters and how to add them to your config, using the editor you were commenting about, so I think it follows. I don't know what prompted your explanations at the end there, but great, we both understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the vim source, it looks like that message can only be
suppressed when launching the executable as `ex` and using its `-s` option, or by not having a console.

Neither approach will work for diffing.

However, the message is only output if there is more than one file
specified on the command line.

So let's trick it:

```
vim a -c "vert diffsplit b"
```

Which basically says "Edit file *a* with vim, and once *a* is loaded, open a vertical split with file *b* and diff them".

Comment: Hey that works!  Awesome, thanks!  Now I have remember where it was that I wanted this.  Good news is I think its still useful info for me.

Comment: If your second file has a space in the path or filename, this solution doesn't work. I worked around it by instead calling vim with the -d flag and sending output to /dev/null, like this (The quotes will correctly pass the arguments with spaces.): vim -d "$a" "$b" >/dev/null

Comment: @DevDaddyNick Doesn't that hide vim altogether for you? It does for me, using `zsh` as my shell, with `oh-my-zsh` based configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I found out later my solution only works when you're not using Vim in the terminal. I was using Macvim, but the next time I tried this solution when SSH'd into another machine, it suppressed Vim altogether.

Comment: For anyone else wanting to dig around in the code, the relevant line in the code as of today's date is [here in main.c](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/bc906e445c77eb4fb5ef97465a45b46499bba111/src/main.c#L369)

Answer (score 0):

--not-a-term option can suppress the message.

`vimdiff --not-a-term a b`

Document
`:h --not-a-term`

Answer (score -1):

Set in your .vimrc

```
set shortmess=at
```

[More tips and triks](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts).

Comment: This does not work for me.  I suspect this only affects messages inside vim not on the commandline.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645736/1081936) on SO, setting this in your vimrc should do the trick:

```
set shortmess=filnxtToO
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work for me either even when I use --noplugin.  I still get a msg.  I'm not talking about the msg in the editor.  After you close the editor, there is a msg and thats what i want to get rid of.  Thanks though